# Find minimal parameter ensuring function is small

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Let $a,b>0,$ and consider the function
$$
f_{a,b}(x)=(1-x^{2a-1})^{x^b}(1+x^{2a+b-1}).
$$
Let $\varepsilon>0,$ be small, and let $b=1+\varepsilon$. I'd like to determine the smallest $a\in (0,1/2)$ such that
$$
f_{a,1+\varepsilon}(x)=(1-x^{2a-1})^{x^{1+\varepsilon}}(1+x^{2a+\varepsilon})\leq p,
$$
holds, for a constant $p$ in $(0,1),$ when $x$ is large enough. You can take $p=1/2,$ or $p=1/e,$ for concreteness if you wish.

Numerically it seems like $a\in (0.4,0.5)$ works.

Comment: Small? $\\ \ \\$

Comment: @Math1000 1/2, as I stated is fine

Comment: Maybe @Math1000 is talking about $\varepsilon$.

Comment: The smaller the better, say $\varepsilon=1/100.$

Comment: FYI : Wolframalpha says that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{0.01,1.01}(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f_{0,1.01}(x)=0$.

Comment: @mathlove please see edit to the answer; any comment appreciated.

Comment: If you mean $f_{a,b}(x)\leq \exp\left[-x^{b+2a-1}\right](1+x^{2a+b-1})$, then I think it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a,b>0,$ and assume that the constraint $a\in(0,1/2)$ holds, thus $1-2a>0.$ Rewriting gives
$$
f_{a,b}(x)=(1-x^{2a-1})^{x^b}(1+x^{2a+b-1})=(1+x^{2a+b-1})\left[\left(1-\frac{1}{x^{1-2a}} \right)^{x^{1-2a}}\right]^{x^{2a+b-1}}
$$
and since $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(1-\frac{1}{n})^n=e^{-1},$ and $n\mapsto (1-1/n)^n$ is monotone increasing and bounded below the limit for any finite $n$, we have
$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f_{a,b}(x)\leq \exp\left[-x^{b+2a-1}\right](1+x^{2a+b-1}) 
$$
and if $2a+b-1>0,$ the right hand side tends to zero.

Comment: @mathlove please see my answer and comment

Comment: (1) Remember that your @mathlove does not work here (I didn't get any notification at all) since I didn't comment here below your answer. (2) You fell in a trap. What you did is completely wrong. (the result may be correct, but that does not justify your way.) Replacing a sub-expression with its limit while calculating the limit of an expression is not allowed in general. What you did is similar to the following way : Since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1n=0$, we get $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac 1n)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+0)^n=1$.

Comment: Ok, understood. Can you prove what I want?